# Two actions in one cronjob command

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I'm having trouble getting this cronjob to work. It works just fine when I execute it in terminal (as root) but it doesn't run in crontab which is executed as root. The funny thing is that when I append logging to the cronjob the log stays empty, it doesn't give any error at all.

I hope someone can help me out with this, thanks in advance.

> @reboot sleep 20 && /usr/bin/forever start /var/web/www/node/App.js

I'm running ubuntu server 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it runs from terminal and not from cron, i would ask you the following:

1) Are you using the full path to the files? Cron runs from a different location than terminal so use full paths.

2) Does your command uses/opens a GUI? You need to tell cron which display to use

Comment: The only command that doesn't have the full path is sleep, tried the full path for sleep as well but that doesn't solve the problem.

No GUI. It works without the sleep and && tough. I think the problem is related to the && sign.

Comment: '&&' is the logical 'AND' so it runs second command only if first one was succesful. Try using ';' instead of '&&' this will run both commands no matter what. If it runs the second command but sleep doesnt work then sleep is the problem

Comment: I'm currently not able to test this but, would ; just launch both commands at the same time? The reason I chose to use && was because the script behind the second commands has dependencies which might not yet have started.

Comment: It will run command 1 first then command 2. I wanted to point out that sleep from cron might be the issue, i have read that there are problems sometimes depending on your cron version. I'll look into it and try to help you

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that for me, going to try and debug tomorrow when I have access to my server to see if sleep is the issue.